# PostgreSQL for Debian vs Redhat (Centos)

Tags: postgresql, centos, debian

PostgreSQL 11 works more efficiently in debian or redhat. Accordingly, I will choose a server and plan training. What are the advantages and disadvantages. Which operating system does the Postgres committee like?

Answer (score 1):

There is no PostgreSQL committee. There is core, but they don't determine which operating systems are supported.

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/supported-platforms.html) (you probably read that):

> A platform (that is, a CPU architecture and operating system combination) is considered supported by the PostgreSQL development community if the code contains provisions to work on that platform and it has recently been verified to build and pass its regression tests on that platform. Currently, most testing of platform compatibility is done automatically by test machines in the [PostgreSQL Build Farm](https://buildfarm.postgresql.org/). If you are interested in using PostgreSQL on a platform that is not represented in the build farm, but on which the code works or can be made to work, you are strongly encouraged to set up a build farm member machine so that continued compatibility can be assured.
>
> In general, PostgreSQL can be expected to work on these CPU architectures: x86, x86_64, IA64, PowerPC, PowerPC 64, S/390, S/390x, Sparc, Sparc 64, ARM, MIPS, MIPSEL, and PA-RISC. Code support exists for M68K, M32R, and VAX, but these architectures are not known to have been tested recently. It is often possible to build on an unsupported CPU type by configuring with `--disable-spinlocks`, but performance will be poor.
>
> PostgreSQL can be expected to work on these operating systems: Linux (all recent distributions), Windows (Win2000 SP4 and later), FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, macOS, AIX, HP/UX, and Solaris. Other Unix-like systems may also work but are not currently being tested. In most cases, all CPU architectures supported by a given operating system will work.

The majority of hackers use Linux, but there are people who develop on FreeBSD, MacOS or Windows.

If you know that PostgreSQL works most efficiently on certain Linux distributions, you know more than I do.

When choosing an operating system for PostgreSQL, I would proceed like this:

1. List the operating systems you are familiar with (or for which your organization has skilled administrators).
2. Exclude all operating systems for which there is not more than one animal in the buildfarm.
3. Exclude Windows.

Then pick any of these.

Comment: I found a test result on the internet and found that it works better on the centos operating system. https://redbyte.eu/en/blog/postgresql-benchmark-freebsd-centos-ubuntu-debian-opensuse/

Comment: That is Xfs vs. ext4 more than Linux vs. FreeBSD, I'd guess.